# Invalid number value

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

i work on a comunautary bot for discord and i have a probleme in my code

this is my code :

```
for (let i = 0; i < body.players.length; i++) {
      if ((body.players[i].votes  >= myToken[0]['palier1'] ) && (body.players[i].votes  < myToken[0]['palier2'] )) {
        embed50.addFields(
          {
            name: body.players[i].playername + ' : ',
            value: body.players[i].votes + ' votes !        ',
            inline: true,
          })
      }else if((body.players[i].votes  >= myToken[0]['palier2'] )) {
        embed100.addFields(
          {
            name: body.players[i].playername + ' : ',
            value: body.players[i].votes + ' votes !        ',
            inline: true,
          })

    }
  }
```

and this is my error :

```
return comparator(input, number) ? Result.ok(input) : Result.err(new ExpectedConstraintError(name, "Invalid number value", input, expected));
                                                                       ^

ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid number value
    at Object.run (/root/bot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:727:72)
    at /root/bot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:113:66
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at NumberValidator.parse (/root/bot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:113:29)
    at validateFieldLength (/root/bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:146:24)
    at EmbedBuilder.addFields (/root/bot/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:190:5)
    at Object.run (/root/bot/commands/topvote.js:111:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  constraint: 's.number.lessThanOrEqual',
  given: 26,
  expected: 'expected <= 25'
}
```

my first if is okay but the second block my code .....

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Protip: `forEach()` is a much cleaner and more modern way to iterate an array.

Comment: It looks like your comparator function returned false and it’s throwing the error you told it to because 26 > 25

Comment: yes but i just want to exec code in my if and if the conditions is false , skip the exec part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace you posted suggests that the error is coming from a function in the Discord.js library called `validateFieldLength`.

Looking at the [source code for this function](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/edadb9fe5dfd9ff51a3cfc9b25cb242d3f9f5241/packages/builders/src/messages/embed/Assertions.ts#L29) in Discord.js it appears the name of this function might be a bit confusing; at first, I thought it was saying the name or value of a field was too long, but it appears that it's actually saying that you're adding too many fields to a single embed, you've added 26 and you're only allowed to add <= 25.

Here is a link to the documentation that goes over the limits for embeds: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-limits

I would suggest you track how many fields you've added so far and when you've hit 25 go ahead and create a new embed (keep an array of these) and attach the next batch to that one. Just note that you can only have up to 10 embeds in a single message so you'll have to stop at 250.

Comment: ok thanks  , to solve it i create a counter who increment each field but the counter still = 1 ..... 

i dont know for what beacause i use cout50++ and count100++ in each if